# Singularity of the following exponential function at z=0

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I am wondering for the following function
$$
f(z) = \frac{e^{- (\log z)^2}}{\sqrt{z}},
$$
what kind of singularity does it have at $z=0$?
I know that in the real line $f(x)$ is $C^\infty$, and I guess that $z=0$ is an isolated singularity and an essential singularity, but I do not have an idea how to show it.

Comment: branch singularity not isolated

Comment: Oh yes, you are right.